# Retrieve all child keys of a node from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

'Test Subject' is a node and it has three child called 'Test Topic 1', 'Test Topic 2' and 'Test Topic 3'. How can I retrieve these three child name (key). I want them to be stored in an arryaList. 
The arrayList would contain these three child name 'Test Topic 1', 'Test Topic 2' and 'Test Topic 3'. Below code didn't seem to work, please help

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Test Subject");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<String> topicList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                topicList.add(ds.getKey());

            }

            sendTopics(topicList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image: as shown]

Comment: log `ds.getKey()` and check what it gives you

Comment: Yes yes it gives the Key string....... Thanks...